Discriminant of quadratic polynomial through the resultant of (f,f')
I would like to calculate the discriminant of $f := ax^2+bx+c$ using the resultant of $(f, f')$.
The formula I found for this is $a_n^{-1}(-1)^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}} \text{res}_x(f(x), f'(x))$.
$\text{res}_x(f(x), f'(x))$ is given by the determinant of the $3\times3$ Sylvester matrix which, if I understood correctly, is
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
0 & a & b \\
2a & b & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
This results in $a(0-b^2)-b(0-2ab)+c(0-2a^2) = ab^2 - 2a^2c = a(b^2 - 2ac)$.
Thus, the discriminant of $ax^2+bx+c$ would be $(-1)b^2-2ac$, which does not result in $b^2-4ac$, as it should be.
There is something crucial missing here, but I am not able to resolve it.

Shouldn’t the middle of the matrix have $2a$?  (You have $a$ there). And also don’t you have the second and third rows switched?

This means that I did not understand how to build the matrix. Wikipedia says "the second row is the first row, shifted one column to the right; the first element of the row is zero" and that the coefficients of f' would come in the (n+1)-th row

See this

here the degree of $f'$ is $n=1$, so the coefficients of $f'$ come in the second row

You have the right idea of how to compute the discriminant from the resultant of $f$ and $f'$,
but you got the Sylvester matrix wrong.
Since the degree of $f'$ is $1$, there is only one row with the coefficients of $f$.
Since the degree of $f$ is $2$, the second row has the coefficients of $f'$ followed by $0$,
and the third row is the second row, shifted one column to the right,
and the first element of the third row is $0:$
$$\begin{vmatrix}a& b& c\\2a&b&0\\0&2a&b\end{vmatrix}.$$
With this, you should get the answer you expected for the discriminant ($b^2-4ac$).

Great! I was confusing the adequate row related to the exponents. Just to see if my reasoning is right, if I wanted to call $n=deg(ax²+bx+c)$, it would not be a problem as long as I put the coefficients of $ax²+bx+c$ in the $(n+1)=3$-th row. The result would be:
\begin{pmatrix}
2a & b & 0 \
0 & 2a & b \
a & b & c
\end{pmatrix}
And the determinant would remain the same.

I think you're right
